# How to connect another computer to the router

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet

I already have a Windows 7 PC connected to my NETGEAR WGR614v10 router and I am able to use internet in that computer.

Now I need to connect one of my old computer to the router to share the internet. It's also running Windows 7. I already connected it to the router via a CAT-5 cable but I am not able to use internet.

The first computer was set up by a technician. Its IP address is `192.168.1.3`, and the default gateway is `192.168.1.1`. On the second PC, I changed the IPv4 to `192.168.1.4` and default gateway and preferred DNS to `192.168.1.1`, but it's not working.

What can I do?

Comment: And, does it work? Basically, you'll just have to copy the settings of the first machine and choose a slightly different IP address (i.e. where the last number is different and not the same as the gateway).

Comment: No it is not working :(, do I have to access the router by typing 192.168.1.1 in a browser?

Comment: You should, yes. I [edit]ed your question with what we know so far and removed a few comments. Maybe you can make screenshots of your connection *Details* of both machines and paste the links to them in your question. I'm out of ideas now, though.

Comment: See if you can ping the gateway, if not ping the local loopback of 127.0.0.1. If loopback works but gateway doesnt check your cable (might be a crossover) and port.

Comment: Copy most of the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) properties for the Local Area Connection from the working computer to the old one -- i.e. Subnet mask, Default gateway, DNS server addresses (or Obtain DNS server address automatically).

Comment: The first computer was set up by a technician you say.  What kind of internet connection are you using?  DSL?  Cable Broadband?  It probably won't make a difference, but there is a possibility that the Router was set up as a bridge if you are using a DSL connection, where the DSL modem is actually handing out the IP addresses... and is limited in how many it can pass out.  Can you provide a screen shot of the main page of your router administration panel?  In all honesty, if the router is set up correctly, you shouldn't have to manually enter any IP settings... the router should pass that on.

Comment: I was unable to open router settings as I did not know the username and password but I was able to connect my 2nd computer by re-installing windows and following the procedures given by slhck.